# Is a dense chain of grounded conductors equivalent to a grounded line conductor in electrostatics？

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

In electrostatics only: consider a set of cylindrical grounded conductors arranged on a line, sharing the same axis.Each has thickness (along the axis) $d$, are evenly spaced by distance $d$, and with radius $r$. To the limit $d\rightarrow 0$, observed from the outside, is this configuration equivalent to a connected grounded cylindrical conductor at the same place?

"Equivalent" here means that for any fixed external static charge configuration, it produces the same field everywhere at least $r$ distance away from the same axis of conductors. I suspect this holds quite directly, but I haven't been able to form a proof by calculation.

You may assume the whole line has a fixed length $L>>r$ (distance from start of first cylinder to end of last) or be infinitely long. The conductors are ideal.

Comment: By a "grounded line conductor" do you mean something like "a line conductor with zero width"?  I don't think that you can do that easily in cases with cylindrical symmetry;  the only solution for which $V$ remains finite as $\rho \to 0$ is $V = $ constant everywhere.  (And of course if you're trying to compare it to a line conductor of finite width, then this will conflict with the $r \ll d$ requirement on your line of spheres.)

Comment: Grounded how? To ground an object, you need to connect it via a conductor to whatever conductor you identify as "ground".

Comment: What do you mean by "height"?  It is evidently not the same as the length $L$.  Is that a thickness?

Comment: @Buzz Edited in post.

Comment: @Buzz I believe it is clear now.